# Renaming filename without highlight extension in Mac

Tags: macos, filenames, rename, highlight, finder

When I press return to rename a filename, automatically, the whole filename is selected (highlighted), including the extension. This is happening in some file types, including .SRT.
In most of the file types, this won't happen. They're most known file types, like JPG and TXT. I tried setting a default app to this file type but that won't fix the problem, I still get the whole filename (including extension) highlighted when press return (to rename the filename).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Your system doesn't recognise .srt as a valid extension. You need to install an app that will "tell" to the operating system about this extension.

An app that did this for me was [VLC](http://www.videolan.org)

You may also find more information here:

https://superuser.com/questions/371892/osx-assign-extension-to-content-kind